# Decode JSON string in Java with json-simple library

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, json-simple

I am new to using the json-simple library in Java and I've been through both the [encoding](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples) and [decoding](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples) samples. Duplicating the encoding examples was fine, but I have not been able to get the decoding ones to work with mixed type JSON.

One of my problems is that there are too many classes in the library which are not properly documented, and for which I do not have the source (in order to be able to read through and understand their purpose). Consequently, I am struggling to understand how to use a lot of these classes.

After reading this example:

```
String jsonText = "{\"first\": 123, \"second\": [4, 5, 6], \"third\": 789}";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

ContainerFactory containerFactory = new ContainerFactory(){
    public List creatArrayContainer() {
        return new LinkedList();
    }

    public Map createObjectContainer() {
        return new LinkedHashMap();
    }                     
};

try {
    Map json = (Map)parser.parse(jsonText, containerFactory);
    Iterator iter = json.entrySet().iterator();
    System.out.println("==iterate result==");

    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=>" + entry.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println("==toJSONString()==");
    System.out.println(JSONValue.toJSONString(json));
} catch(ParseException pe) {
    System.out.println(pe);
}
```

from the [json-simple official decoding tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples), I tried to decode this JSON:

```
{
"stat":{
    "sdr": "MAC address of FLYPORT",
    "rcv": "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",
    "time": "0000000000000",
    "type": 0,
    "subt": 0,
    "argv": [
        {"type": "6","val": "NetbiosName"},
        {"type": "6","val": "MACaddrFlyport"},
        {"type": "6","val": "FlyportModel"},
        {"type": "1","val": id}
    ]
}
}
```

I am writing following code to decode:

```
    String jsonString = "{\"stat\":{\"sdr\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\",\"rcv\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\",\"time\": \"UTC in millis\",\"type\": 1,\"subt\": 1,\"argv\": [{1,2},{2,3}]}}";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject newJSON = jsonObject.getJSONObject("stat");
    System.out.println(newJSON);
```

But it doesn't work. Infact I was not able to get the unmodified example working either, and the original authors have not explained their code.

What is the easiest way to decode this JSON as shown?

Comment: Can we see your code for decoding a stat?

Comment: Have you checked with example 5(Stoppable SAX-like content handler) in [JSON official decoding tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples)

As I can see that the code is intended for single dictionary(Map)/Array. But you are trying for the json with maps in a map(multiple maps). If I am wrong correct me.

Comment: @ram2013: ya.. my what I need to decode is maps in maps... and I guess this is one of them. as if I get the value for "stat" I can use it for further JSON decoding.

Comment: Easiest way if you ask me? This >> https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Well first of all your `jsonString` is not a valid json. And what is that thing inside of `argv` ??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the best and easiest code:

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String str[])
    {
        String jsonString = "{\"stat\": { \"sdr\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\", \"rcv\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\", \"time\": \"UTC in millis\", \"type\": 1, \"subt\": 1, \"argv\": [{\"type\": 1, \"val\":\"stackoverflow\"}]}}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject newJSON = jsonObject.getJSONObject("stat");
        System.out.println(newJSON.toString());
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(newJSON.toString());
        System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("rcv"));
       System.out.println(jsonObject.getJSONArray("argv"));
    }
}
```

The [library definition of the json files are given here](http://json.org/java/). And it is not same libraries as posted [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/), i.e. posted by you. What you had posted was [simple json library](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) I have used [this library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java).

You can [download the zip](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/archive/master.zip). And then create a `package` in your project with **org.json** as name. and paste all the downloaded codes there, and have fun.

I feel this to be the best and the most easiest JSON Decoding.

Comment: How do we add the escape `\` to `"` in `JSON`? I don't want to do a `String.replace()`

Comment: I keep getting this output 

"A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]"

My JSON content does not have anything before the second "{"

Comment: org.json is amongst the worst solution available. Its performance is terrible and feature set inexistant. That is mainly because it was developed early in the days of json by its creators as a proof-of-concept library. 
Consider performance before choosing: https://github.com/fabienrenaud/java-json-benchmark (done with JMH). jackson is your winner here.

Comment: first link is 404

Answer (score 4):

Well your jsonString is wrong.

```
String jsonString = "{\"stat\":{\"sdr\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\",\"rcv\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\",\"time\": \"UTC in millis\",\"type\": 1,\"subt\": 1,\"argv\": [{\"1\":2},{\"2\":3}]}}";
```

use this `jsonString` and if you use the same `JSONParser` and `ContainerFactory` in the example you will see that it will be encoded/decoded.

Additionally if you want to print your string after `stat` here it goes:

```
     try{
        Map json = (Map)parser.parse(jsonString, containerFactory);
        Iterator iter = json.entrySet().iterator();
        System.out.println("==iterate result==");
        Object entry = json.get("stat");
        System.out.println(entry);
      }
```

And about the json libraries, there are a lot of them. Better you check [this](http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/).

Answer (score 3):

This is the JSON String we want to decode :

```
{ 
   "stats": { 
       "sdr": "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", 
       "rcv": "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", 
       "time": "UTC in millis", 
       "type": 1, 
       "subt": 1, 
       "argv": [
          {"1": 2}, 
          {"2": 3}
       ]}
}
```

I store this string under the variable name "sJSON"
Now, this is how to decode it :)

```
// Creating a JSONObject from a String 
JSONObject nodeRoot  = new JSONObject(sJSON); 

// Creating a sub-JSONObject from another JSONObject
JSONObject nodeStats = nodeRoot.getJSONObject("stats");

// Getting the value of a attribute in a JSONObject
String sSDR = nodeStats.getString("sdr");
```

Comment: Letter 's' is missing at "stat", should be JSONObject nodeStats = nodeRoot.getJSONObject("stats"); right ?

Comment: It looks like `JSONObject` no longer has an initializer that accepts a String.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of downloading separate java files as suggested by Veer, you could just add this [JAR file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip) to your package.

To add the jar file to your project in Eclipse, do the following:

1. Right click on your project, click Build Path > Configure Build Path
2. Goto Libraries tab > Add External JARs
3. Locate the JAR file and add