# How would I split this string?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

How would I go about cutting this giant string? I need the data of the `first ID`," preferably for the string output to be:

```
"id":1,"name":"site1","has_doneit":true,"destination":"4613"
```

Is this possible? Or if not any other ways of grabbing the name:"site1" and the has_doneit:true would be perfectly fine.

```
   {"needs_complete":true,"has_done":true,"sites":[
    {"id":1,"name":"site1","has_doneit":true,"destination":"4613"},{"id":2,"name":"site2","has_doneit":true,"destination":"4613"},{"id":3,"name":"site3","has_doneit":true,"destination":"4339"},{"id":4,"name":"site4","has_doneit":true,"destination":"4340"},{"id":5,"name":"site5","has_doneit":true,"destination":"4341"},
    {"id":6,"name":"site6","has_doneit":true,"destination":"4622"},{"id":7,"name":"site7","has_doneit":true,"destination":"4623"},{"id":8,"name":"site8","has_doneit":true,"destination":"4828"},
    {"id":9,"name":"site9","has_doneit":true,"destination":"4829"},{"id":10,"name":"site10","has_doneit":true,"destination":"4861"}]}
```

Comment: With a JSON parser.  Don't try to use `split` or regular expressions for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like a JSON string so use a Json Parser...

### PHP: [JSON_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$parsedStr = json_decode($yourString, true);
```

you can access sites array in `$parsedStr['sites']`

So, to access the id of the first site:

```
echo $parsedStr['sites'][0]['id'];
```

### Java

check this answer in SO [Decoding JSON String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574482/decoding-json-string-in-java)