# Read JsonElement from Json file?

Tags: java, arrays, json, org.json

I need to read `JsonElements` from given `JSON` files. I am using `org.json.simple` jar.

Here is the sample of my json:

```
[{
 "Submission ID": "9938306",
 "Lat": "17.447191666666665",
 "Long": "78.38849"
 },
 {
  "Submission ID": "9938306",
 "Lat": "17.447191666666665",
 "Long": "78.38849"
}]
```

I wrote this following code to read `JsonArray` but not able to figure out how to read `JsonElements` from it:

```
try {
      JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
      Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("sampleData.json"));
      JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
      Iterator iter = array.iterator();
      while (iter.hasNext()){

      }
    }
```

How can I read all `JSONelements` for each `JSONarray`? For example:

## EDIT

I want to iterate all `JsonElements` in `JsonAray`. In my given Json I do have `submission ID`  and `submission_ID`. Key is dynamic in some point and I need to read it and want to apply some `regex` on it.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574482/decoding-json-string-in-java) post it might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Actually they are reading JsonObject by giving `.get("")` function. I want to iterate it to each JsonElement for an each arrays

Comment: @LuciusHipan It's a different question because They are getting JsonElements with the help of "key_name". In my scenario I want to iterate over all of the keys.

Answer (score 3):

running code. try it

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {

             JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
              Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/stpl/NIKHIL/text.json"));
              JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
              for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
              {
                 JSONObject objects = (JSONObject)array.get(i);
                 System.out.println(objects.get("Submission ID")+" "+objects.get("Lat")+" "+objects.get("Long"));
              }   
        }
    }
```

my text.json

```
[{
 "Submission ID": "9938306",
 "Lat": "17.447191666666665",
 "Long": "78.38849"
 },
 {
  "Submission ID": "9938306",
 "Lat": "17.447191666666665",
 "Long": "78.38849"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jackson ? Which provides good utilities to parse JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("d://sample.json"));
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
Iterator iter = array.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) iter.next();
    Iterator<String> keys = json.keySet().iterator();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        System.out.println("Key :" + key + "  Value :" + json.get(key));
    }
}
```

This will iterate each key and value of given JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code,

```
try {
      JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
      Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("sampleData.json"));
      JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
      for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
          JSONObject obj=array.getJSONObject(i);
         System.out.println(obj.get("Long"));
      }
    }
```

*Note:not compiled*