# Parsing string from php inside java

Tags: java, php, parsing, delimiter

I am reading data from my database using PHP and I get the result by using echo which I read inside my java code.

The result from my string is as follows:

```
String mydata;
mydata = "["sdfsd_-sdf","gdf5g7_","fsdfl50","sdfsf_5-X"]"
```

I had like to split it into array as get this result (without quotes sign):

```
array[0] = sdfsd_-sdf
array[1] = gdf5g7_
array[2] = fsdfl50
array[3] = sdfsf_5-X
```

I have used this code to do it:

```
String[] my_array = mydata.split(",");
```

However my result is:

```
array[0] = "["sdfsd_-sdf""
array[1] = ""gdf5g7_""
array[2] = ""fsdfl50""
array[3] = ""sdfsf_5-X"]"
```

How can i get rid of the `] [` and "`?`

Thank you

Comment: 1) `myData = myData.subString(1, myData.length() - 1)`. 2) `array[x] = array[x].subString(1, myData.length() - 1)`.

Comment: If this is JSON which you are passing then I would have thought https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574482/decoding-json-string-in-java would be what your after.

Comment: It is indeed a json that I obtain from my PHP 'echo json_encode($rows)' however when I obtain it in my java doInBackground task it is returned as string