# How to get this data in json fromat?

Tags: android

I got this data in `PayUMoney` and to show the user But problem how to get this data in `json` or key value pair format any one know that please help!!

```
addedon=2019-11-21+17%3A06%3A42&amp;productinfo=FINE&amp;firstname=Creataum+Test+User&amp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the string is both URL encoded (the `%3A`) and JSON encoded (the `&amp;`).

You have to decode the string and then split by `'&'` and then split each pair to key and value by `'='`.

You can see here how to JSON decode: [Decoding JSON String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574482/decoding-json-string-in-java)

URL decoding can be done with Java's `URLDecoder` class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

For this example I'll just assume the only encoded characters are `%3A` and `&amp;`.

```
String payumoney = "addedon=2019-11-21+17%3A06%3A42&amp;productinfo=FINE&amp;firstname=Creataum+Test+User&amp;";

// String decoding.
payumoney = payumoney.replaceAll("%3A", "-");
payumoney = payumoney.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");

HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] pairs = payumoney.split("&");
for (String pair : pairs) {
    String[] keyValue = pair.split("=");
    params.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that u have got it as String following code will print the key value pair from the string

```
String x ="addedon=2019-11-21+17%3A06%3A42&amp;productinfo=FINE&amp;firstname=Creataum+Test+User&amp;";
    String pair[] = x.split("&amp;");
    Log.e("pairs", Arrays.asList(pair).toString());
    for (int i=0;i<pair.length;i++){
        String key[] = pair[i].split("=");
        Log.e("pair:","key= "+ key[0]+" value= "+key[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a String with mixture of URL encoding (like `%3A` for `:`) and HTML characters (like `&amp;` for `&`).

I believe you can try decoding it and then split data like say by `&` to get data for each key and then further split by `=` to get value for that key.

For URL decoding you can try like

```
String decoded = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use String replaceAll() function to create the json.

```
str= str.replaceAll("=", "\"");
str= str.replaceAll("&amp;", "\",\"");
str= "{\""+ str+ "\"}";
```