# JSONPath: Get field starting with @ in escaped json string

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I want to get a nested field in a json string using JSONPath.

Take for example the following json:

```
{
  "ID": "2ac464eb-352f-4e36-8b9f-950a24bb9586",
  "PAYLOAD": "{\"@type\":\"Event\",\"id\":\"baf223c4-4264-415a-8de5-61c9c709c0d2\"}"
}
```

If I want to extract the @type field, I expect to do it like this

```
$.PAYLOAD.@type
```

But that doesn't seem to work..

Also tried this:

```
$.PAYLOAD['@type']
```

Do I need to use escape chars or something?

Comment: That seems like encoded JSON. Don't think JSONPATH can parse that.

Comment: That was what I needed to know. Than I'll parse the encoded json in Java first! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Posting my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72274141/jsonpath-get-field-starting-with-in-escaped-json-string?noredirect=1#comment127687362_72274141) as an answer</sub>

---

```
"{\"@type\":\"Event\",\"id\":\"baf223c4-4264-415a-8de5-61c9c709c0d2\"}"
```

Isn't JSON, it's a *string* containing *encoded JSON*.

---

Since JsonPath can't decode such string, you'll have to use a language of your desire to decode the string.

Eg: [Decoding JSON String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574482/decoding-json-string-in-java)